# Error: Expected ',' separator in xcode 8

Tags: swift, ios10, xcode8, swift2

I migrated my code to Xcode 8 Swift 2.3, and since then getting error in the following line:

```
func imageForUrl(urlString: String, completionHandler:(image: UIImage?, url: String) -> ())
```

Error : stating Function types cannot have argument label 'xxxx', use '_' instead. (where xxxx are image and url, both)

following which when I Fix the above errors, it gives Expected ',' seperator and Expected type errors, for the same line which transforms to

```
func imageForUrl(urlString: String, completionHandler:(_ image: UIImage?, _ url: String) -> ())
```

How can I fix this issue? please help.

Comment: Please post an actual code and not a screen shot

Comment: @user3351949 updated my question,

Comment: removing _ will make the code back as was initially,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you are using swift 3.
Move last ) before the return

```
func imageForUrl(urlString : String, completionHandler :(image : UIImage?, url: String) ) -> () {


}
```